# lookup filter on custom object

Tags: validation-rule, lookup-filter

I have a custom object `A` that has a lookup to `Contact`.
In the `Contact` object I have a lookup to `user`. I want to filter the lookup to contact on object `A` so the only contacts allowed are the ones related to a user with a certain profile. I tried lookup filter but it's not possible and I'm having a hard time trying to make it with a validation rule.
Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a custom text field on Contact, `RelatedUserProfileName__c`. And then have two autolaunched Flows:

1. on Contact that populates the `RelatedUserProfileName__c`.
2. on User that triggers on a change to Profile, uses GetRecords to get all Contacts that lookup to that User, and then loops over them to update the `Contact.RelatedUserProfileName__c` field.

Then you could filter the lookup based on `RelatedUserProfileName__c`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for alternatives:

1. you can do the verification in a before trigger on the concerning object. if the conditions does not meet do an add error . to know more about add error click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm)
   .Example of how to implement it go [here](https://www.avenoir.ai/post/apex-trigger-adderror#:%7E:text=An%20addError()%20method%20is,Account.)
2. Make the field read only on the pagelayout. then create a screen flow or lightning component to fill the field. you will have more control on the data you are adding.